# Calculating tied ranking in php with pagination

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

This is my first question here, so please tell if something is unclear or you need to know more. Hopefully I've provided the information you need.

I got a page calculating cycling rankings in Norway. The riders gets point in each race, and I calculate their overall ranking. Until now have calculated their ranking after each race and saved their overall points and rank in the database. This have been frustrating, since I had to run the calculation after every small change or update.

In the updated page I calculate their overall points and ranking using this PHP-code inside a loop when displaying the table (all three rank variables are set to 0 before the loop):

```
$rank_tmp++;
if ($rankpoints!=$row["points"]) {
$rank=$rank_tmp;
}
echo $rank
```

This simple code works well, and give me ranks with ties.

The challenge is when I use pagination to split the results over each page.

In the query and code I've added:

```
LIMIT $starting_position, $records_per_page";

$starting_position=($_GET["page_no"]-1)*$records_per_page;
```

To get the ranking to continue on page two I expanded the loop with:

```
$rank_tmp++;
if ($rankpoints!=$row["points"]) {
$rank=$rank_tmp;
}
echo $rank + $starting_position;
```

This works as intended, if I set ´$records_per_page=50´ the first rider on page two gets rank 51 and so on.

The problem is: if rider 50 and 51 both have the same number of points, rider 51 will still get rank 51 and not 50 as he should.

So how do I calculate ranking, with ties, when using pagination?

Comment: Can you add more code, this is a bit unclear..

Comment: How large is the ENTIRE data set?

Comment: @Strawberry:
For the season 2015 there is around 8,5k results (1 rider in 1 race is 1 result). 1,1k different riders, and 110 races.

Comment: @alex: please tell me where its unclear and I'll add more code.

Comment: I guess your problem has solution:  if rider 50 and 51 both have the same number of points, rider 51 will still get rank 51 and not 50 as he should.

Then retrieve the records not from 50 not from 51, and check the check the score of 50  and 51 and display the rank accordingly

Comment: @JitendraKumar.Balla: Do you mean that I should set the limit lower to check the rank and then don't show all output?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't have time to tailor directly to your answer, but here's something I put together for adding a ranking index to my paginated query results.

```
foreach($queryResults as $index=>$result)
{
    $currentPage = ceil( $_POST['pageOffset'] / $_POST['limit'] );
    $rank = ($index+1)+($_POST['limit']*($currentPage)));       
}
```

Comment: If you're going to post an answer, please do attempt to take the time to tailor your code to OP's situation, so as to make your answer more useful to him and others reading this question